# Not able to create folder and file inside webContent of java web application after deploying the war file on server

Tags: tomcat7

I have developed a web application in java, there is a one senior where i am generating xml and placing it in folder in webcontaint>myxml>****.xml and converting that xml in pdf and showing the result. its work fine in my local machine. The Problem is when i deployed that application the folder and corresponding xml is not get created. I am unable to understand what is the problem. My tomcat version is 7. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Thanks in advance for the replay.
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the user that deploys the application doesn't have privileges to create files and folders. Check this.

Comment: thanks for the replay emilio. can you tell me how to give privilege to create files and folder to tomcat user.

Comment: You can change permissions and owners with chmod and chown commands (linux)

Comment: i have windows-7 installed in my system.

Comment: Look if the directory where user tomcat has to put the war is property of another user. That's could be the problem if for example this user is root. Not sure how to do this in windows.